# Extensible Angular controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I wrote an application which is the skeleton for multiple projects. So I wrote the controllers filling the scope with the minimum variables and callbacks used in my templates. Multiple projects will use this code base and create their own application by extending my controllers and my templates. They want for instance add new variable to the scope or new callback in some controllers. I need to find a simple way for them to do that without changing my modules.

So let's say I have a very simple controller:

```
angular.module('controller-a').controller('a', function($scope) {
  $scope.foo = 'bar';
});
```

And this controller is accessed via basic routing like:

```
$routeProvider.
       when('/a', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/a.html',
            controller: 'a'
       }).
```

And one wants to add a new value to the scope like `$scope.baz = 'klux';`). How can one perform that?
Is it possible to change `a` in place to avoid having to redefine the routing or must one absolutely create another controller for this?

**I am not in the standard use case where I have one controller whose functions are needed by multiple ones in the same application. Each controller will be overridden once or not and that's it.**

What look closest to what I want is:

```
angular.module('controller-b', []).controller('b', function($scope) {
  var original = $controller('a');
  original($scope);
  $scope.foo = 'bar';
});
```

But then I need to change the routing to use b instead of a, is there any way to update a in place?

Comment: "extend the content of the 'a' controller without changing the code". So, what will be the purpose of the controller?

Comment: the initial controller provide some basic features common to multiple projects, then multiple projects would want to change in their own way the scope without having to change/copy the initial code (a has a lot more code in practice)

Comment: @joliver that is called service, factory. Software patterns are clear regarding this type of issues and solutions

Comment: What I have in my controllers is just very basic scope logic (declare variables, callbacks), I just want people to declare other scope variables and callbacks additionally to the one my controller defines. I don't think this is the purpose of a service (never in a single angular application my controller 'a' will be overriden twice, there will be multiple applications made by different people overriding each a).

Comment: let me invite you to use TypeScript I think that would solve your problem. Your mind is set in "the ways of a different language" that it not javascript

Comment: thanks, but if TypeScript compiles to js and is the solution I should be able to do this in js without having to change my whole codebase just for this feature ;)

Comment: Typescript does not require you to change your codebase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do what I needed by overriding the application and the route mapping and defining a new controller extending the original one like this:

```
var app = angular.module('app-ext', [ 'app', 'ngRoute']);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
    when('/a', {
      templateUrl: 'partials/a.html',
      controller: 'b'
    });
});
app.controller('b', ['$controller', '$scope', '$http', '$location', function($controller, $scope, $http, $location) {
  // Apply original controller
  $controller('a', {'$scope' : $scope});
  // Add own features here
  $scope.foo = 'bar';
}]);
```

Which works just like I expected.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to add new values to multiple controllers, you could inject a service in all of them and `$watch` for changes there. Your developers change the service but not the controller. I think this is kind of the point of Services.

```
angular.module('controller-a', ['whatever']).controller('a', function($scope, MyService) {
  $scope.foo = 'bar';
  $scope.$watch(MyService.return_new_values(), 
    function(newValue, oldValue) {
        // do somethign with the values?
    });
});

angular.module('controller-b', ['whatever']).controller('b', function($scope, MyService) {
  $scope.foo = 'bar';
  $scope.$watch(MyService.return_new_values(), 
    function(newValue, oldValue) {
        // do somethign with the values?
    });
});

angular.module('whatever').factory('MyService', function() {

    var myService = {};

    myService.developer_x_var = 'klux';
    myService.developer_y_var = 'foo';

    myService.return_new_values = function() {
        var array_of_new_values = [myService.developer_x_var,
                                   myService.developer_y_var
                                   ];
        return array_of_new_values;
    }

    return myService;
});
```

Comment: And what to do with the new values? Appart if I misunderstood this logic should not be in the base a it should be in the extending module.

Comment: What you do with your values depends on your use case of course, so it's up to you. As long as you get your dependencies right it doesn't really matter what is in which module. That depends on the structure of your app.

Comment: I reworded my question which should be clearer now: I am responsible of writing module a, and other developers will want to extend the controller in their module b without being able to change module a, so it does matter what is in which module. So I don't think you provide a solution to this problem.

Comment: Hm, ok. You want a base controller and then 'inherit' from that and extend it? I think controllers are not really meant to be used that way. Whatever logic happens there should be structured differently. Controllers are rather short pieces of code that glue your views to more complex logic.

Comment: Exactly, and yes that's where my first days of research led to. I'm digging into Angular source code now to see if this can still be done cleanly, as soon as I have something I'll answer myself for feedbacks.